# Filter in PROPS in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have code like below

```
created () {
     EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);
},
props: ['applicants',],
data() {
        return {
            values: [],
      }
},
methods : {
        formated (item) {
         //some code here
        }
}
```

I have some checkboxes in another component. I am trying to catch values of those checkboxes in this component. After catching those values I would like to filter the props `applicants`. I would like to find out which `applicants` have those values of checkboxes. Then I would like to pass them to `values[]`. Then I would like to iterate those values in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments I believe this is what you need to do. You can use the prop as well as the data passed through the event bus in the formatted() method. You need to combine the two and set them to values. I have pasted code below. However, not knowing the structure of either two objects I can't help you further. This is just plain JavaScript. So probably you need something like Object.assign or the .filter or .map methods.

```
created () {
 EventBus.$on('change',this.formatted);
},
props: ['applicants'],
data() {
    return {
        values: [],
      }
},
methods : {
    formatted (item) {
        this.applicants // access the data from your prop
        item // access the data from your event bus
        this.values = someCombinationOf(this.applicants, item)
    }
}
```

After setting values from the formatted () function you can iterate over it (for example with v-for). Whenever an event is emitted through the event bus this will update your component. Whenever the prop changes the component will be updated also.

Comment: Thanks @Imre_G for your reply. How can I use computed property ? How can I iterate over computed property ? How can I pass values from `created()` to `computed` property and methods ? How can I establish relation among all those ? Actually I am new in `vue.js`.Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. I think I understand what you want better now.

Comment: Thanks @Imre_G for your reply. My `props` from one component, `EventBus` is coming from another component and I am working on a 3rd component. That's why I need to work with `props`. I did like you before posting this question. I have to work with `props` inside method and created. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @Imre_G . Is it possible to pass `props` inside `watch` ? Thanks.

Comment: You can, but it is not necessary as Vue watches props by default

Comment: Thanks @Imre_G. I need to catch an event (like checkbox change) within method. How can I do that ? Thanks.